# Salesforce Trust API

Tags: api, trust

I am trying to automate the process of checking for an outage or service degradation for my particular instance and send an email to out Help Desk with the instance id and start time of the incident. I also need to log the incidents in our database. Where do I get this information? Also, how can I tell when an incident has been resolved?

Comment: I wanted to try this but never got really far so I'm curious to see what you find. I know that you can subscribe to the status per instance via RSS but I'm not sure that gets you everything you need.

Comment: Have you looked into this - https://ifttt.com/applets/169172p-performance-degradation-on-salesforce-na13 ?

Comment: @brezotom, I looked at the applet. I can simulate what it is doing but I need more details of the outage such as the incident id, incident start time etc for reporting purposes

Comment: Did you ever manage to get anything working with this?